# Deserialising this kind of nested JSON structure delivered by reqwest

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde-json

Someone may well point to a duplicate on this. But I have searched. There are lots of questions on the subject, but none I've really seems to help.

The structure of my delivered JSON (from Elasticsearch) is like this:

When I go:

```
let json_hashmap: HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&text).unwrap();
```

I get this:

```
{
    "hits": Object {
        "hits": Array [
            Object {
                "_id": String("Ybgt6ooBpXznUptX4lR2"),
                "_index": String("booby"),
                "_score": Number(1.0),   
                ... (other keys)
            ],
            ... (multiple other hit-hit Objects in the Array)
         ],
         ... (other keys)
    }
    "key2": String("my arbitrary string value"),
    "key3": Number(1.0),
    ... (other keys)
}
```

It's not that the keys and nested array of hit-hit "dictionaries" are unpredictable. I can devise a `struct` for these hit-hit dictionaries. But how can I actually obtain the array of hit-hits?

Because as can be seen, the level 0 dictionary (outer dictionary) has ONE key which decodes to an inner dictionary ("level 1") containing an array of inner-inner dictionaries ("level 2").

But the level 0 dictionary has keys other than "hits" which decode to other values. And indeed the level 1 dictionary may also have keys other than "hits".

Is there a way of stipulating that **one particular key** in the "level 0" (outer) dictionary decodes to `HashMap<String, Value>` and that **one particular key** in that dictionary decodes to `Vec<MyStruct>`?

NB I can get access to some object if I go

```
let outer_hits = &json_hasmap["hits"];
let inner_hits = &outer_hits["hits"];
```

Printing this using `{:#?}` shows this:

```
Array [
    Object {
        "_id": String("Ybgt6ooBpXznUptX4lR2"),
        "_index": String("booby"),
        "_score": Number(1.0),
        "_source": Object {
            "docx_id": Number(14),
            "last_modif_ms": Number(1596958203000),
            "ldoc_type": String("docx_doc"),
            "path": String("D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-03.docx"),
        },
    },
    Object {
        ...
```

... but, for example, although this is said to be type `Array`, my attempt to go `inner_hits.len()` won't compile: I get " ^^^ method not found in `&Value`". Strange kind of an "array". How can I extract something more useable?

`text` at the very start is:

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "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",
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 3,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 5303,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "booby",
        "_id": "Ybgt6ooBpXznUptX4lR2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "docx_id": 14,
          "last_modif_ms": 1596958203000,
          "ldoc_type": "docx_doc",
          "path": "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-03.docx"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "booby",
        "_id": "jLgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "docx_id": 12,
          "last_modif_ms": 1596958248000,
          "ldoc_type": "docx_doc",
          "path": "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-01.docx"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "booby",
        "_id": "1bgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSX",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "docx_id": 20,
          "last_modif_ms": 1596958053000,
          "ldoc_type": "docx_doc",
          "path": "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-09.docx"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "booby",
        "_id": "7rgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSm",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "docx_id": 21,
          "last_modif_ms": 1596958032000,
          "ldoc_type": "docx_doc",
          "path": "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-10.docx"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "booby",
        "_id": "_rgt6ooBpXznUptX4lS2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "docx_id": 22,
          "last_modif_ms": 1596957990000,
          "ldoc_type": "docx_doc",
          "path": "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-11.docx"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It'll be better if instead of the debug representation of the `serde_json::Value` you will show the actual JSON.

Comment: Thanks, but can I clarify what you're asking for there? Because I used `text` at the start because `json` raised an error, due to the too-complicated contents. Do you mean the bit at the end?

Comment: I mean the actual JSON text, before parsing it. It is just easier to understand.

Comment: OK have done that... but I'm not sure how to pretty-print a json string in Rust! Looking that up...

Comment: Please remove the backslashes. And there are plenty of JSON formatters online.

Comment: Hopefully that's a bit better. These remaining double-backslashes are path separators (in W10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to model your own types that reflect the expected JSON structure instead of using a generic `Value`. You can do that by implementing [`serde::Deserialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Deserialize.html). Something like this (only some fields implemented):

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::json;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Response {
    // _scroll_id
    // took
    // timed_out
    // _shards
    hits: HitsResponse,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct HitsResponse {
    // total
    // max_score
    hits: Vec<Hit>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Hit {
    // _index
    _id: String,
    // _score
    _source: HitSource,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct HitSource {
    // docx_id
    // last_modif_ms,
    // ldoc_type
    path: String,
}
```

Parsing your JSON into a `Response` above would yield this:

```
let response: Response = serde_json::from_str(&text).unwrap();
```

```
Response {
    hits: HitsResponse {
        hits: [
            Hit {
                _id: "Ybgt6ooBpXznUptX4lR2",
                _source: HitSource {
                    path: "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-03.docx",
                },
            },
            Hit {
                _id: "jLgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSG",
                _source: HitSource {
                    path: "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-01.docx",
                },
            },
            Hit {
                _id: "1bgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSX",
                _source: HitSource {
                    path: "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-09.docx",
                },
            },
            Hit {
                _id: "7rgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSm",
                _source: HitSource {
                    path: "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-10.docx",
                },
            },
            Hit {
                _id: "_rgt6ooBpXznUptX4lS2",
                _source: HitSource {
                    path: "D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-11.docx",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0fbf7c86ad85c62a385a6791f038fb4e)

And if you're using reqwest, you can use [`.json`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json) directly instead of `.text` or `.bytes` + `serde_json` (by enabling its `"json"` feature).

Comment: Thanks. I had stumbled on `serde_json::from_value` in the mean time... but this looks like the best solution. I didn't realise these `struct`s could exclude certain fields/keys, which appears to be what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

To extract workable types (`Vec`, `HashMap` etc.) from [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html) you can either pattern-match it or use the helper methods `as_X()` (e.g. `as_array().unwrap().len()`).

However, it is always better with serde to work with typed deserializations instead of the generic `Value`. Both access is easier and deserialization is faster.

Comment: Thanks, `as_X` is very helpful. Indeed, I would like to use a typed deserialization, but as you can see, in my case I have a dictionary with one key among others being an inner dictionary, with one key of *that* being a Vec (or array) of dictionaries which are the structs which can be characterised. The puzzle is how to apply that structuring to the array of inner dictionaries. I'm sort of looking for a function which will do "as_struct(MyStruct)".

Comment: ... but `as_object` for each element in that array delivers something perfectly workable.

Comment: As for "pattern-match" to obtain a type, having searched I'm wondering whether you perhaps mean `serde_json.from_value()` ...?

Comment: @mikerodent No, I meant `match x { serde_json::Value::Array(x) => ` of `if let serde_json::Value::Array(x) = x`.

Comment: @mikerodent I don't see the confusion of typed deserialization, don't think of them as dictionaries, think of them as objects with fields of different types and deserialize it like so: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=488de1f1d7268b039aa0524ed297fe0f). Or maybe you've missed the entire point of the serde system?

Comment: @kmdreko In fact I've missed it so much I've never even heard of it ever, and thus have missed it 100%. Which doesn't prevent me looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

As a barely out-of-nappies Rust newb (as may be apparent) I hesitate to offer this solution, bearing in mind the knowledge of the 2 people who've taken an interest in this question. But this seems to work. Whether it's a good solution I don't know.

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct HitSource {
    docx_id: usize,
    last_modif_ms: usize,
    ldoc_type: String,
    path: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Hit {
    _id: String,
    _index: String,
    _score: f64,
    _source: HitSource,
}

...
let hits_dict = &json_hashmap["hits"];
let hits_array = &hits_dict["hits"].as_array().unwrap();
...

for hit in *hits_array {
   /*
NB each hit looks like this:   
{
    "_id": String("1bgt6ooBpXznUptX4lSX"),
    "_index": String("booby"),
    "_score": Number(1.0),
    "_source": Object {
        "docx_id": Number(20),
        "last_modif_ms": Number(1596958053000),
        "ldoc_type": String("docx_doc"),
        "path": String("D:\\My Documents\\doc\\IT_Diary\\IT Diary $UPD 2018-09.docx"),
    },
}      
   */
   
   let hit_result: Result<Hit, _> = serde_json::from_value(hit.clone());
   info!("{:#?}", hit_result);
}
```

... this does indeed deliver a non-error `Result<Hit, _>`, which seems OK.

However, the solution of kmdreko seems to be the canonical one: the crucial thing with his solution is that any keys which are found in any of these dictionaries/maps which can't be interpreted as the desired `struct` structure simply get ignored: in the case shown, keys such as "_scroll_id", "took", "timed_out", "_shards", etc.

I found that if I attempted to do away with `struct Response` (his outer dictionary/map `struct`) and used `HashMap<String, HitsResponse>` instead, this raised an error... because of those other keys, whose values can't be interpreted as a `HitsResponse`. If all of them could, it seems that would work OK.